# Find the power series of the 3 functions together

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

$$f(z)=3e^z+2ze^z+z^2e^z$$

In the first part of the problem, I had to find the power series of each term, which are listed below.

$$3e^z=\sum_{n=0} \frac{3z^n}{n!}$$

$$2ze^z= \sum_{n=0} \frac{2nz^n}{n!} $$

$$z^2e^z= \sum_{n=0} \frac{n(n-1)z^n}{n!} $$

Then, to get the expansion of the larger function I simply used the same Taylor terms for each of the 3 individual functions and added them together to get each term of the larger function. This resulted in the following:

$$3+\frac{5z}{1!}+ \frac{9z^2}{2!}+ \frac{15z^3}{3!}+ \frac{23z^4}{4!}$$

But now I can't figure out a way to represent that in sigma notation. Term 2 is the term 1 +2. Term 3 is the term 2 +4. Term 4 is term 3 +6...etc...

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven for what purpose?

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven if they ask start at the same $n$, then they'll all have the same $\frac{z^n}{n!}$.

Comment: You are good....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power series are linear, so just combine into one notation:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{3z^n}{n!}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2nz^n}{n!}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n(n-1)z^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty [3+2n+n(n-1)]\frac{z^n}{n!}$$

$$=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n^2+n+3)\frac{z^n}{n!}$$

Comment: When solving one of the original 3 power series, if I find that the first term in the expansion starts with $0$, do I still include that term by instantiating at $n=0$? Or do I have to shift over to the first non-zero term by starting at something like $n=1$?

Comment: You are fine with what you have.  Starting at $n=0$ makes the constant $0$ anyway.  My initial statement was off as I did not take into account that fact that the constant term would be 0 since you have $n$ in the numerator.  What you have is fine, and then you just add the terms together.  It would have been nice if you had a product that was factorable, but it works as is....

Comment: Works for me, thanks!